# How does Java delimit its code into lines using ';' when having to deal with them in for-loops, etc?

Tags: java, parsing

So as the title says, my question is simple. As java uses semicolons inside for-loops, how does it know if the semicolon is in a for-loop and when it is the end of a line?

You could do something like read each line, converting them into a single char stream, but how does the parser know which semicolon belongs to a for-loop and which is the end of a line?

Something like this is what I mean

```
String line = bufferedReaderObject.readLine(/*params*/);
char[] stream = line.toCharArray();
```

But how does the parser know that the semicolons in

```
for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

are not the semicolons at the ends of a line?

EDIT:
To make my question clearer, java uses semicolons in a number of different places (eg: in forloops and to terminate statements) how does it differentiate between a statement terminator, and a semicolon inside something like a for loop

NOTE: after reading a comment on this question, are the things inside a for loop's condition (inside brackets "()") also statements?

Comment: A semicolon isn't the end of a line. It is a statement terminator. Whether it occurs inside or outside a for-loop is irrelevant. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, @user207421. I'll edit the question to hopefully make my question clear

Comment: The parentheses inside a for-loop contain three things: (1) a statement, which can also be a declaration and initializer; (2) a condition; and (3) a statement. They are separated by semicolons. I don't know what else to say. Compilers don't find the semicolons first and then process what's before them, if that's what you're thinking, and they don't process in lines either. They work token by token, left to right.

Comment: To answer your NOTE ... oh wait, I already answered it, before you asked. And the compiler 'knows' when it is inside the for-loop parentheses.

Comment: So Statements inside for-loops are evaluated just as a normal statement? If so, then the compiler would just have to regard the semicolons as statement terminators, right @user207421?

Comment: The short answer to all of this is that Java *doesn't* 'delimit its code into lines using semicolons'. The compiler parses according to the syntax. The semicolons do a certain job inside the for-loop parentheses, and a certain job outside them. It doesn't have to decide 'what' the semicolons are. There isn't a problem here to be solved.

Comment: Oh ok. So I was literally thinking in the wrong direction all along. Thanks a lot for the answers, @user207421.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parser isn't doing anything so simple as just chopping up the program into bits wherever there's a semicolon.  Not all semicolons are created equal. The parser decides what any particular semicolon, or any other symbol, means by taking into consideration the entirety of what came before that semicolon or other symbol.  In other words, *parsers understand **context***.

So the semicolons that separate the controlling expressions in a `for` statement won't be confused for statement-enders because the parser is quite aware that it is in the middle of parsing a `for` statement, and in the middle of a `for` statement a semicolon is merely a  "control expression separator", not a "statement-ender".

As for how the parser does all this, it's way too complicated for this small space.  You need a year of university courses and a nice fat textbook or two to cover it all really well. Or just jump right in with [bottom-up parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing) or [top-down parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing) on Wikipedia, if you dare.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. And, also, I had read all about those parsers before, and couldent understand some bits, so came here looking for answers

Comment: Like I said, year's-worth of university courses... And some parsing techniques are less "intuitive" (read "harder to understand why they work") than others.  For example, [recursive descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser): super-intuitive; [LR, SLR, LALR and friends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser): not so much.

Comment: A year's worth of university courses! ha! I'm just a 15yr old curious kid. Some time before uni for me. =)

Answer (score 1):

Java is a [free-form language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free-form_language) which means that whitespace (spaces, tabs, new lines) have no meaning. We use whitespace to format code so that it's easier to read for a human. For example,

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++)
```

has exactly the same meaning as:

```
for(int
i=0;i
<j;i
++)
```

but I think you'll agree that the former is easier to comprehend for a human. However a compiler would handle them in exactly the same manner. So semi-colons are used to separate lines as such but they have meaning in Java.

The compilation process has many steps but the two relevant ones here are: (a) [lexical analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) which converts code into a stream of tokens (while throwing away elements such as comments and whitespace); and (b) [parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing) which attempts to make sense of the tokens while looking for syntax errors. These steps are essentially independent of how the code appears to a human.

In your example, the lexical analyser would produce a stream of tokens, such as:

```
keyword "for"
left parenthesis
keyword "int"
name "i"
operator equals
number "0"
semi-colon
```

and so on. The parser would then recognise this as a `for` statement.

Comment: I do know what you pointed out. I just did not understand the fact that java uses the syntax to determine when a statement 'ends'